# How do map designers subconsciously lead players?

Tags: game-design, level-design, world-design

Playing a game like Uncharted I’m struck by the illusion of an open world that it feels like I’m making my own choices to walk through, but I always stumble on the next plot point or encounter, so clearly I’ve been led by the designer. How?? It feels like I’m deciding whether to go left or right or whatever but clearly I’m responding to subtle cues — what are they?

Comment: This blog post might be interesting to you: [Signposting tips and tricks](https://gamedevfocus.blogspot.com/2014/12/signposting-tips-and-tricks.html)

Comment: I was going to suggest "density of detail" as a way this is done, but this good old blog explains it far better than I can: https://nodraw.net/2010/08/tf2-density-of-detailing/

Comment: Not an answer, but if you want to explore the concept of "illusion of choice", I recommend playing "The Stanley Parable".

Comment: Useful to learn the [difference between a maze and labyrinth](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/144103/313144).  Both are twisty-turny, but in one, you don't have to find your way.  Also, individual maps may have one way in and one way out, thus making the overall plot "on rails" despite having freedom to roam within one map or zone.  You can usually tell that you've been funnelled when you see the cut-scene.

Comment: _The most useful life lesson videogames have given us, is that if you keep encountering enemies on your way, it means you're in the correct path_

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I haven't played Uncharted, so I haven't analyzed Uncharted. What I know about it is mostly from YouTube. Something I can tell is that it is very linear. If there are options, they might be using false branches.

Anyway, I can share what I have pieced together about designing landscapes and guiding the players… But know it mostly not from Uncharted.

---

**On the language of games**

Games are a communication medium, between the designed and the player, it has a language. And through the language of games the player gets to know how the designer thinks.

Some of the language is unique of the game, some of the genre, and some is more general. And it might become second nature, to the point that you are not aware when you are picking the clues.

Some of the language of games is lifted from actual nature, such as color and shapes associated with danger or safety. *See also the psychology of shapes, the psychology of colors, and the psycology of music.* You can be more explicit, and use enemies, explosions, and so on to signal danger and have the player avoid a path.

Some of the language is transferred knowledge, from other games in the genre. And some is unique of each game.

Speaking of affordances: you want to define standard sizes, so the player can pick on which spaces they can go through, and over what things they can jump over. *And it also makes things easier for animation.*

*Games that rely on scripted sequences instead of a sandbox approach, might be expecting a particular solution from the player. The player will learn to think "what the designer want me to do". And through the language of games the player gets to know how the designer thinks. Although, we should aspire to the player thinking "what can I do" or better yet "what do I want to do" instead of "what the designer want me to do".*

---

Out of what I can tell you about Uncharted, is that it uses color as affordance. However, you need to learn it. You are not born knowing that you climb on yellow. So, you see, the same game can also be less intuitive to a less experienced player.

For example, an experienced player would try different inputs on their controller and see what they do. *And be annoyed by a tutorial.* But we don't know if a beginner would do that or not. Some might assume that what they are told is all they can do. And this might mean they miss on possible alternative ways to progress.

For an example of bad design affecting experienced players and beginners differently: you see an space wide enough to go through, and there are no visible enemies or hazards… But when do you try to go there, a cut-scene plays where enemies attack you and you die, requiring to try the area again. Were you too slow? Were you not sneaky enough? Or perhaps it is designed so that going that way is an insta-death and give you the illusion that there are more possible paths than there actually are at the expense of player frustration? Perhaps as experienced player you take the fact that it is a cut-scene as clue, but a beginner might struggle with it (or not, it depends on the person).

---

**Guiding the player**

*I suppose I don't need to talk about non-diegetic solutions (e.g. minimaps).*

I want to start on the more liminal side of the spectrum: You can quite literally tell the player about a place. In fact, many games would have a quest that makes you go there. Similarly, if there is a companion NPC, it can provide hints if the player gets lost. Also on the liminal side is using a trail of collectibles or easy to kill enemies to guide the player. And, of course, an actual path on the ground.

On a similar note, if exploring is rewarding, the players will be inclined to explore more. And rewarding here can be objects either hidden or hard to reach, but it can also be a a good looking landscape, or some dialog, or environmental storytelling, or make it a hidden shortcut.

By the way, either for the good looking landscape or other opportunities, you can take take advantage of the techniques used in photography to draw attention to the place you want them to go. And those techniques include framing, radial lines, concentric shapes, color and light contrast. And, of course, you can use motion to draw attention. *Light is also particularly useful to draw attention. For example, have a window or hole in the ceiling for sunlight to enter - or simply a lamp - that highlights an object that the player should interact with.*

*Another thing I can tell from Uncharted is that it has a cover mechanic. So you put enemies that attack the player from the direction you want the player to go, the player takes cover, and now you know the camera is looking that way. You might be paying attention to the enemies, but you can also see the path fordward.*

On a less linear game, instead of teaching players to explore, you want to teach players to keep momentum. So any side path, if there are any, is not rewarding. Instead you reward going forward and going forward fast, so players learn to not stop to explore.

To ease this, you want to make sure the path forward remains in view if the player is following it (and thus, there is no geometry occluding it, and there are no sharp turns). You may take advantage of elevation to give the player an advantage point if going downwards. Or a clear milestone ahead if going upwards.

*To have the player keep going and not stop to explore, you can also add a sense of urgency via narrative. And have music reinforce it.*

---

First and foremost, having tall structure that can be seen from afar is good to help players orient themselves. However, each of those structures can be taken as a promise to the player that they can get there. The players might be inclined to pick one such structure and start going that way, so you can take advantage of that. On a similar note, use the terrain to frame where you want the player to go, and to hide where you don't want them to go.

*By the way, the textbook frame opportunity is when the player is going through a door. But you can do it with terrain features too.*

You would also take the opportunities to reveal new destinations. For example: the player climbs on to something, or goes pass an obstacle, or opens something, so that they can now see a place that was obscured before, and of course that is the next place - or one of the next places - they should go.

Second, you can to make the terrain/architecture/structures distinct for distinct areas. *A good idea for this is to use psychology of shapes. You may also color code areas.* Thus, when the style changes, the player knows they are getting to a new are to explore. There the players will take more time to look around.

Also, you want the terrain to close into pathways and open up to to wide areas, so the player can think in terms of a discrete number of possible paths they can follow, and areas to explore. Instead of picking arbitrary directions in one giant area.

*Please notice that what I'm saying is also good for culling geometry out of view.*

*By the way, sound and music can also help signal to the player where in the world they are. Or even where to go, for example if you can hear enemies in a particular direction.*

---

You can make paths more clear by drawing lines. Either literally draw paths in the terrain (for example it can be following the side of a terrain feature), or have have repeated structures that serve as milestones. Also, avoid sharp angle that might be misunderstood as the path ending abruptly.

When the player is walking down a path, you can guess where they are looking, and that gives you the opportunity to frame other things without taking away camera control※. You can also be somewhat more subtle about the paths, for example have wildlife move in a particular direction.

※: If players need to backtrack to an area, they will approach it from the opposite direction, and that is an opportunity to show them things they might have missed on the first pass. Which reminds me, you use this to hide things you want the player to miss, and reveal them later this way. Then recurring - or good explorer - players would be able to get them early, which could be a soft sequence break.

When the player is exploring an area, you can make things stand out by their size (this comes natural if you are already using tall structures that can be seen from afar). The big structure suggest the player that there is more stuff inside, and that it is important. So it feels natural to want to explore it.

---

You can use music cues to hint the player what behavior they should have. The classic example is music for combat, and music for safety. But you can also have music for exploration, and music for linear traversal. Like I said before, you may give the linear sections a sense of urgency, and support it with music. Do the equivalent with open areas. And then the player will associate the music with the kind of area they are in, and that clues them into the desired behavior.

---

**False branches**

You can have multiple traversal options, even depicted as paths, that are not actual branches (they don't lead to new areas). Instead they either:

- Loop back over the same path. Which you could do with a one way connection or a hidden connection, so you know on which direction the player enters the loop. If it is a one way connection, it could also be opened as a shortcut.
- Dead ends. These are the small sibling of the loop, in that you can think of them as a loop where the second half is the same as the first half but going backwards. You may put optional loot there.
- A shortcut. For example, without drawing attention to it, or by making it hard to access. You can have two paths that lead to the place, except one is shorter than the other.
- A redundant path. So the path splits in two, but they are actually equivalent.
- The evident path. For this one you use everything you can to hint the player to go there.

*Since I'm saying that once open, the loop can be a shortcut, and that the shortcut could be hard to access… Instead of a one way connection, you can make the loop use a connection that is hard to traverse in one direction, but easy on the other. So it is both.*

And so the player might be exploring, and going out of the intended path, even feeling smart for finding a shortcut… But they end at the same place, not matter what.

---

**Addendum**:

You can close the path behind the player to reduce the area they have to explore to find the path forward. This is useful in games that require a lot of backtracking, but you don't want the players to try to backtrack their way back to the beginning of the game.

Also, remember you close a path in a way that requires the player to have an object or ability to open it or bypass it. You may even have such paths not naturally read as paths. So the player is only looking for them once they got said item or ability. Making them virtually invisible beforehand.

Comment: Nice! Also: Showing a part of the map that is not yet attainable, as a reminder that more lies ahead. It might be an item up in a not yet reachable place, or something visible through a window but behind a locked door. Give something for the player to anticipate, which somewhat amplifies the feeling of achievement when it is attained. The original DOOM and DOOM II come to mind as examples. There are rooms you can see, but it's clear from door markings they cannot be accessed without a certain key card. That also reminds the player of the next goal: to find the key. This encourages exploration.